# Question to find next number after observing the previous ones

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to I find next number after the following numbers (in place of question mark)

1. $5682:714$
2. $9516:156$
3. $3498:1113$
4. $8257: ????$

Please I want to know the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $\color{blue}{15}\color{red}{7}$, as we have 
$\color{blue}{8}\color{red}{25}\color{blue}{7}$ where $8+7=15$ (sum of outer $2$ digits) followed by $2+5=7$ (sum of inner $2$ digits).

Comment: we cant write 2+5=07 or something greater in this manner.

Comment: Looking at the other three results, if the sum is single digit, we don't put a 0 before it.